# onClick não funciona no ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios, jquery-mobile

Eu estou a desenvolver a aplicação em windows, mas depois através do phonegap vou passa-la para uma aplicação ios, que utiliza o plugin IScroll para percorrer a minha lista.

**Problema:**

Em cada `li` tenho uma `div` que tem o evento `onClick`, para que quando essa `li` for clickada eu chamar uma função. E isto funciona muito bem no google chrome que é onde ando a testar. Mas quando passo para o ipad, este evento é completamente desprezado

Já estive à procura de soluções para este problema, mas todas as alterações que tenho feito (adicionar o **CSS** `cursor:pointer`, por exemplo), não me têm ajudado a ultrapassa-lo.

**JavaScript**

```
    createList: function(p_id)
    {

          var lv_linhaDoc = '<li id="lis_' + p_id + '" class="listItem">' +
          '<div class = "alinhar1" onClick="lis.Click(' + p_id + ', false)">' + 
                '<div class="ui-grid-a" style="font-size: large">' +
                  '<div class="ui-block-a"><p class="header" style="font-size: medium"><strong>' + 4 + '</strong></p></div>' +
                  '<div class="ui-block-a"><p class="line label"><strong>Data Criação</strong></p></div>' +
                  '<div class="ui-block-b"><p class="line value" style="text-align: right">' + '13/2/14' + '</p></div>' +
                  '<div class="ui-block-a"><p class="line label total"><strong>  Valor</strong></p></div>' +
                  '<div class="ui-block-b"><p class="line total" style="text-align: right">' + 13 + ' ' + 15 + '</p></div>' +
              '</div></div>' +
                  ' <input type="button" class=" button_add" onClick="lis.Detail(' + p_id + ')" />' +
          '</li>';

        return lv_linhaDoc;
    },
```

P.S:

1. Esta função acima é chamada recursivamente
2. a class `listItem` é só de identificação, ou seja, não tem **CSS**

**CSS**

```
.alinhar1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 90%;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Peço imensa desculpa, não devo ter sido suficientemente explicito. O `onClick` que me está a falhar é o primeiro de todos, o da class `alinhar1`.
O que me mais faz confusão é que eu noutra class do projecto tenho também um `onClick` e esse funciona-me na perfeição:

**JavaScript** (que funciona)

```
linhadeDetalhes: function (p_item) {
        detail.items += '<li><div onClick="detail.matInfo(' + "'"+ p_item.info + "'" + ')"><p><strong>' + p_item.info + '</strong></p>' +
                            '<p>' + p_item.quantidade + ' ' + p_item.unidades + '</p></div>' +
                            '<p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-aside-value"><strong>' + p_item.preco + ' ' + p_item.preco2 +' </strong></p></li>';
    },
```

Comment: Para dispositivos móveis alguns browsers entende o `onClick`, outros entendem o `tap` ou o `touchstart`. Para mais informações acesse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358292/capture-tap-event-with-pure-javascript

Comment: @DiegoSouza eu actualizei a pergunta

Comment: Beleza, mas está dando algum erro ? O que mostra o Inspect Element ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza Não dá erro nenhum. Funciona perfeitamente, mas apenas aqui no google chrome. Quando passo para o ipad, o primeiro `onClick` deixa de funcionar

Comment: Está usando o Safari ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza nop. Isto é uma aplicação no ipad.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24718/discussion-between-msm-oliveira-and-diego-souza).

Comment: @DiegoSouza descobri o erro. :P Pensei assim: "Porque é que na outra classe do projecto está a funcionar e aqui não?" "Esta tem o plugin IScroll e a outra não." O problema está no Iscroll. Encontrei a solução aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768037/enable-click-events-in-iscroll-on-mobile-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já resolvi o problema. O problema era porque o plugin IScroll estava a bloquear-me os `clicks` e `taps` das `li`'s que estão lá presentes.

Adicionei estes dois atributos ao método que inicializa o Iscroll e começou a funcionar:

```
    myScroll = new IScroll(wrapper, {
            click: true,
            tap: true,
            ...
```

Descobri por aqui a solução: [Enable click events in iScroll on mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768037/enable-click-events-in-iscroll-on-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o evento tap em vez do click.

```
$('.button_add').bind('tap',function() {  alert('Deu certo!'); });
```

Comment: fiz um update à pergunta